# Python Runtime Error not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, error-handling, runtime-error

I have an input file as follows

```
3
01
0010100
11011
```

and the output is supposed to look like this

```
LIVES
DIES
LIVES
```

However my code returns,

```
DIES
[1, 0]
DIES
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
DIES
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

I am working with this problem (https://open.kattis.com/problems/whowantstoliveforever). Basically, I am looking at the current value of the bits at positions i−1 and i+1 (if they exist; otherwise assume them to be 0). If my program sees exactly one 1, then the next value of the i-th bit is 1, otherwise it is 0. All the bits change at once, so the new values in the next state depend only on the values in the previous state. The universe is dead if it contains only zeros.

I am trying to say if the program catches infinite loop that probably means the universe will live, 0 and 1s keep repeating continuesly. And if `len(set(x))` is 1 then I am returning False.

```
import sys


def get_bit(bits, i):
    if 0 <= i < len(bits):
        return int(bits[i])
    else:
        return 0


def print_result(boolean):
    print("LIVES" if boolean else "DIES")


def recursion(in_list, output_list):
    try:
        for index in range(len(in_list)):
            if (get_bit(in_list, index-1) == 0 and get_bit(in_list, index+1) == 0) or (get_bit(in_list, index-1) == 1 and get_bit(in_list, index+1) == 1):
                output_list.append(0)
            elif(get_bit(in_list, index-1) == 0 and get_bit(in_list, index+1) == 1) or (get_bit(in_list, index-1) == 1 and get_bit(in_list, index+1) == 0):
                output_list.append(1)
        if len(set(output_list)) == 1:
            return False
        else:
            in_list = output_list
            output_list = []
            recursion(in_list, output_list)
    except RuntimeError:
        return True


num_cases = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
for i in range(num_cases):
    _list = []
    case = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    for char in case:
        _list.append(char)
    output_list = []
    print_result(recursion(_list, output_list))
    print(output_list)
```

Is there any way to handle this problem if not `except RuntimeError` won't work?

Comment: Please explain your problem in the question itself.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks, updated it.

Comment: OK, trying to detect this based on recursion limit errors is the wrong approach. You need to keep track of previous states and detect when you enter a state that you've already seen. If this happens, you know there's either a loop or a steady (non-dead) state.

Comment: And don't do it recursively, refactor back to iterative.

Comment: @Blorgbeard when I tried doing it iteratively, I assumed it'd be hard to know exactly when to stop.

Comment: Yeah, so you stop when you hit all zeroes, or when you hit a state that you already hit before.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the recursion limit is not ideal for a few reasons. But mainly the algorithm "if it lives for X generations, then it probably lives forever" is fundamentally not going to cut it for longer input.

Here's the skeleton of how I'd implement this:

```
def get_new_state(old_state):
    pass # todo: implement

def is_dead(state):
    pass # todo: implement

def determine_fate(state):
    seen = set()       
    while True:
        if is_dead(state):
            return "DIES"
        if state in seen:
            return "LIVES"
        seen.add(state)
        state = get_new_state(state)
```

I'm using a set to remember old states. If we ever see a state more than once, then we've hit a loop or a steady state, so we know the result is "LIVES". If this doesn't happen before we hit the empty state, then we know the result is "DIES".

Note that you'd have to change from using lists to represent states, since lists are not hashable and therefore cannot be added to a set. I'd use strings.

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with "if it lives for `2**len(input)` generations, then it lives forever" though...

Comment: True, if you set the limit to the maximum number of states that approach does work. I still wouldn't abuse the recursion limit in order to count states though!

Answer (score 0):

First, @Blorgbeard is right, don't do this. This is a terrible anti-pattern.

---

But to answer your titular question: The reason your snippet didn't work even for small cases is the way you did the recursion:

```
recursion(in_list, output_list)
```

If the universe lives, then at some point this indeed throws a `RuntimeError` (more precisely a `RecursionError`) for exceeding the recursion limit (which is not very large; on my testing environment it was 2961, so don't expect it to solve any large instances correctly). Which means some instance of this call will return `True`. However, that return value is unseen, and the enclosing function finishes without returning anything, which means that it returns `None`.

To catch a `RecursionError` correctly, either put the `try`-`catch` block out of the recursive function, or pass whatever value you want up the stack like this:

```
return recursion(in_list, output_list)
```

This gives the correct return value for the small cases you gave.

---

What you really should do, though, is to recognize that you don't yet know an efficient algorithm to solve this (the problem statement allows for up to 200000 characters in each input case). Therefore you should print all the states a particular input goes through, and look for patterns.

It is possible that this problem is simply too difficult for you, and you should either give up on it, or find a description of the algorithm on the internet if you think programming practice is more important for you. Then again, it doesn't require any algorithmic knowledge (apart from basic things like recursion) nor any mathematical knowledge (apart from basic things like parity), so it can be a good exercise.